# How to define a $P$-primary component of $M'\ne \{0\}$ in $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, definition

The definition of a $P$-primary component of $0$ in $M$ is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138335/the-notion-of-p-primary-component). But I haven't found a definition of a $P$-primary component of a nonzero submodule $M'$ in $M$. Is there such a notion? If so, what's its definition in terms of the terminology in the question cited above?

Comment: I'd change your $M'$ to $N$ in order to avoid some confusion with the linked question. Then consider $P$ minimal over the annihilator of $M/N$. We say that $\ker(M/N\to(M/N)_P$ is the $P$-primary component of $N$ in $M$.

Comment: Btw, I don't think that Eisenbud's textbook is the best place to learn about primary decomposition of modules. For instance, Matsumura's approach is more natural and the proofs are pretty clear. (Not mentioning Bourbaki which is the best.)

Answer (score 0):

From Bourbaki,  *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. IV *Associated Prime Ideals and Primary Decomposition*, §2:

> Let $A$ be a noetherian ring, $M$ an $A$-module, $N$ a submodule of $M$. We call $\,$ *primary decomposition of $N$ in* $M$ a finite family $(Q_i)_{i\in I}$  of submodules of $M$, primary w.r.t. $M$, and such that $\;N = \bigcap\limits_{i\in I} Q_i$.

$Q$ is said to be *primary w.r.t.* $M$ if $\:\operatorname{Ass}M/Q$ contains only one element.

Comment: But these definitions don't say anything about a $P$-primary *component* of $M'\ne 0$ in $M$.  I was hoping to get a definition of that in terms of localizations, generalizing the definition in the cited question.

Comment: With Bourbaki's notations, the $P$_primary component of $N$ in $M$ is the submodule $Q_i$ such that $\operatorname{Ass}(M/Q_i)=\{P\}$, unless I misunderstand what you're asking..